# Visual Studio crashes when typing in editor

Tags: visual-studio-2010, editor, crash, intellisense

I have been using VS2010 for a few weeks but for the past few days it has been totally unusable. When I type anything into the editor Visual Studio throws an exception, then I get lots of intellisence errors (the code is fine, I can compile it if I run before trying to use the editor) - here is the log message:

```
  <entry>
    <record>241</record>
    <time>2011/01/25 08:30:34.109</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Editor or Editor Extension</source>
    <description>System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type &apos;System.__ComObject&apos; to interface type &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsTextReplaceEvents&apos;. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID &apos;{CF9928D9-65AE-4319-A446-94ED5C45ECDE}&apos; failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetCOMIPFromRCW(Object objSrc, IntPtr pCPCMD, Boolean&amp; pfNeedsRelease)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsTextReplaceEvents.OnReplace(ChangeInput[] pCI)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.VsTextBufferAdapter.OnTextBufferChangedHighPriority(Object sender, TextContentChangedEventArgs e)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Utilities.GuardedOperations.RaiseEvent[TArgs](Object sender, EventHandler`1 eventHandlers, TArgs args)</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>242</record>
    <time>2011/01/25 08:30:34.125</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Editor or Editor Extension</source>
    <description>System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type &apos;System.__ComObject&apos; to interface type &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.IVsTextStreamEvents_Private&apos;. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID &apos;{96FC7D44-BCDD-4F00-AE4D-07E26B2C0E52}&apos; failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetCOMIPFromRCW(Object objSrc, IntPtr pCPCMD, Boolean&amp; pfNeedsRelease)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.IVsTextStreamEvents_Private.OnChangeStreamText(Int32 iPos, Int32 iOldLen, Int32 iNewLen, Int32 fLast)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.VsTextBufferAdapter.OnTextBufferChanged(Object sender, TextContentChangedEventArgs e)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Utilities.GuardedOperations.RaiseEvent[TArgs](Object sender, EventHandler`1 eventHandlers, TArgs args)</description>
  </entry>
```

Comment: So when does VS actually crash?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This seems like it might be due to some info missing from the registry on your computer. If you go to the [MS Connect website](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/546369/) you'll find a discussion about this issue and what seems to be a solution as well.

Solution (copied from that page):

Using regedit look at the following key:

On 32-Bit Windows: `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{73B7DC00-F498-4ABD-AB79-D07AFD52F395}\InProcServer32]`
On 64-Bit Windows: `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{73B7DC00-F498-4ABD-AB79-D07AFD52F395}\InProcServer32]`

The "(Default)" value should be one of the following:
On 32-Bit Windows: `"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSEnv\TextMgrP.dll"`
On 64-Bit Windows: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSEnv\TextMgrP.dll"`

Comment: This worked perfectly. I ran into the above problem all of a sudden in Visual Studio 2012 and this solved it.

Comment: This key already existed on my system but still VS2017 instantly crashes typing in VB.NET code (even in a newly created project). This behaviour came from one day to the next.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a problem with an extension or add in. Disable them all then re-enable one by one and see if one of them is acting up..

Comment: ho1's answer is correct; it's a bug related to entries missing in the registry, not an extension.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this stopped VD from crashing but intellisence still went crazy for a while, but it seems to have sorted itself out now, thanks for the help!

Comment: The problem started after months of use, I think it is a problem with a VS extension not installing/uninstalling correctly (I suspect one of the reverse engineer extensions I tried)

Comment: In my case this changed nothing. VS instantly crashed even when started in safemode.