# Visual studio crashes when type something in the Code Editor

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-6

Suddenly my Visual studio 2015 update 3 started crashing when i try to type some code. It was working until friday. Something happened over weekend. I have 5 projects ( 4 Class Libraries & 1 web project) in my solution. VS gets crashed only when i try to type something in the code editor of a `Data` project which is a class library. I am using EF Code First but i don't think this issue is related to code. This could be related to something else.

I have looked into `Activity.log` and found that it's due to some corrupt `ComponentCache`. I cleared `ComponentModelCache` but still problem persists.

Any suggestion is hightly appreciated.  `Activity.log` entry is pasted below for your reference. I am sure many of you must have experienced this issue.

```
 <entry>
    <record>633</record>
    <time>2016/07/04 13:55:53.621</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Editor or Editor Extension</source>
    <description>Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensibilityHosting.InvalidMEFCacheException: The Visual Studio component cache is out of date. Please restart Visual Studio.&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensibilityHosting.FaultCatchingAssemblyLoader.&lt;LoadAssembly&gt;b__15_0(AssemblyName assemblyNameParam)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensibilityHosting.Utilities.SafeGetOrAdd[TKey,TValue](IDictionary`2 dictionary, TKey key, Object lockObj, Func`2 valueFactory)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensibilityHosting.FaultCatchingAssemblyLoader.LoadAssembly(AssemblyName assemblyName)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.Reflection.ResolverExtensions.Resolve(ConstructorRef constructorRef)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeComposition.RuntimePart.get_ImportingConstructor()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.RuntimePartLifecycleTracker.CreateValue()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.Create()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveNext(PartLifecycleState nextState)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveToState(PartLifecycleState requiredState)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.GetValueReadyToExpose()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass15_0.&lt;GetExportedValueHelper&gt;b__0()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass15_0.&lt;GetExportedValueHelper&gt;b__0()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.DelegateServices.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass2_0`1.&lt;As&gt;b__0()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Tagging.Implementation.TagAggregator`1.GatherTaggers(ITextBuffer textBuffer)</description>
  </entry>
```

Comment: Try to reset your VS2015. It happens to me also yesterday. After reset, all ok. Tools->Import and Export Setting->Reset All

Comment: When i try to `reset all` i am getting an error saying 
`Error 1:  An error occurred while importing settings for 'CoffeeScript' [code 5611].`. I don't use CoffeeScript.

Comment: still no luck.  VS crashes as soon as i type something.

Comment: Hello, check this please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791519/visual-studio-crash-when-typing-in-editor

Comment: Try removing CoffeeScript, then reset all, clean without any addin.

Comment: @polisha989  Thanks. but i have gone through that post earlier. `Registry` keys are fine.  That post targets a different error.

Comment: @Venky: You can find your current settings file in `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Settings` and replace  `CurrentSettings.vssettings` file with one of the default profiles in `%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Profiles` folder.

Comment: The exact same thing happened to me with the VB.NET code editor in VS 2017, strangely enough also over the weekend.